# What is good approach to calculate effect size?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, z-score

Given two OLS, I'd like to calculate the effect size of different coefficient from same predictor from two regressions. What would be good method to calculate the effect size?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What's would you think of just using the coefficients and saying that as your $x$ variable changes by one unit, the $y$ variable changes by the coefficient?

Comment: Regression coefficients are effect sizes themselves.